# Outlook Addin shows same dialog in other opened Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook AddIn that shows a dialog every time a user sends a message.

I am opening the dialog and getting the message information on *onItemSend* event. This is working as expected: Once the message is sent, it opens a dialog, with some information such as recipients, subject, etc.

The problem is when the user keeps Outlook opened and send a message from another source, such as phone or tablet. After the user sends the message, the opened Outlook will display the dialog, even if it was not sent from that instance.

For instance, there was a user that has the addin installed at his home and office. He kept his home Outlook opened and after a busy day at work, sending several messages and displaying the dialogs, he checks his outlook at home. It will be several opened dialogs, regarding the messages he sent during the day.

Is there a way to restrict the dialogs? Kind of open the dialog where the user is sending the message from? This way the user will not have any dialog in any other opened outlook...

Thanks

> **EDIT**

Just checked my code and there was a misunderstand (of my part off course). I removed some code from the methods, just to be easier to read...

There are two event handlers in the code:

```
Outlook.Folder sentbox;
Outlook.Items myOlItems = null;

this.itemsendhndler = newicrosoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
this.Application.ItemSend += itemsendhndler; 

this.hndler = new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Application_ItemAdd);
sentbox = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
myOlItems = sentbox.Items;
myOlItems.ItemAdd += this.hndler;
```

Then, in Application_ItemAdd there is the onItemSend method, that I thought it was the Application_ItemSend...

```
void Application_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
    this.onItemSend(Item);
}


private void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = item as MailItem;

    if (mail == null)
        return;

    //Make sure this is a E-mail message
    if (string.Compare(OutlookItemHelper.GetMessageClass(mail), "IPM.Note") != 0)
        return;

    mail.DeleteAfterSubmit = false;
    Outlook.Folder sentFolder = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
    if (sentFolder != null)
        mail.SaveSentMessageFolder = sentFolder; // override the default sent items location
    Cancel = false;
}

private void onItemSend(object Item)
{
    Outlook.MailItem itm = null;
    itm = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

    using (ExampleDialog dlg = new ExampleDialog())
    {
        //code after actions...
    }
}
```

Anyway, the dialog is not being opened in Application_ItemSend event. My bad guys...I learnt something new today!

Thanks guys and I apologize for the newbie question...

Comment: Impossible... What code do you have in the add-in?

Comment: Hi Eugene. I just checked the code and I confirmed that the dialog was being opened in itemAdd instead of itemSend. Thanks for the help. I have edit my question, adding the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? Application.ItemSend will only fire on the instance of Outlook that actually sends the message. Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder on the other hand will fire in each instance of Outlook. Is that what your code is doing?

Comment: Hi Dimitry. I just checked the code and I confirmed that the dialog was being opened in itemAdd instead of itemSend. I will make this change, opening the dialog in Application.ItemSend event. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey Dimitry, after debugging the code I could figured out what happened. We used to open the dialog in Application.ItemSend event but as we need to save a copy of the message as an attachment, the message itself were added with "This message has not been sent yet". Then we moved the open dialog to Items.ItemAdd event in order to be able to get the message with  "Sent" status. The deal is: opening from itemsend, will show single dialog and "Unsent" message. Opening from itemadd, will show multiple dialogs and "Sent" message. What Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Stamp the outgoing message with a special property (some kind of id, a guid would be good) in the ItemSend event and add the id to a list. When ItemAdd event fires, you can read the property and see if it is in the list. If yes, popup the dialog, if not, just ignore the message. This way the dialog will only popup in the instance that actually sent the message.

Comment: What a great solution! Thank you Dmitry! You are awesome!

Comment: Make sure you use PropertyAccessot.SetProperty (pick up a named property guid and id), not UserProperties.Add as that will cause your message to go out in the RTF (TNEF) format.